# Duplicate a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I need to be able to duplicate a list of lists in python.

so for example right now I have a function that returns a list.

this is always lists within a list.

for example:

```
 myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

now I need to create two copies of this list (myList1, and myList2), each of which is separately mutable (for example, if I edit myList1, myList2 will not be edited)

I have tried everything.

from the simple:

```
 myList1 = myList[:]
 myList2 = myList[:]
```

to the more complicated:

```
 myList1 = []
 for ch in myList:
      myList1.append(ch)


 myList2 = []
 for ch in myList:
      myList2.append(ch)
```

nothing works. If I change a value in one list:

```
 myList1[0][0] = 10
```

both lists become:

```
 [[10,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything you have tried so far only creates a shallow copy of the outer list.  To create a deep copy, use either

```
copied_list = [x[:] for x in my_list]
```

using a list comprehension or

```
copied_list = copy.deepcopy(my_list)
```

using the [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

```
myList2 = copy.deepcopy(myList1)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/FiWZR)